# Garbage values are showing on browser after publishing using pentaho report designer

Tags: pentaho

I have created a report using postgres dataset in pentaho. Report is running and parameter values are showing correct in pentaho but when it is published, on browser , garbage values are coming at the place of space

Product category value 'Meat, polutry & seafood' is showing as `Meat,&#x20;Poultry&#x20;and&#x20;Seafood`.

can any one help.

Answer (score 0):

That's not garbage. That's a whitespace, html encoded. Check the connection settings and parameters of your jdbc connection and make sure white spaces are properly processed and displayed. It may happen that they are stored as html entities in the database and when you query the database in a web browser the whitespaces are displayed as true spaces, despite the storage being in html entities.